image from uint16 array from serial port
I'm getting values uint16 (RGB565) from serial port. The array contains 76800 uint16 values from an image 320x240. Right now I'm just sending the test bar image and I'm getting this image:

which it seems to be generated multiple times by the python script I used, which is this:
def TakePicture():
    xdim = 320
    ydim = 240
    i=0
    RGB_list.pop(0)
    im = Image.new("RGB",(xdim,ydim))
    for k in range(76800):
        value1=int(RGB_list[k])
        RGB_values.append(value1)
    for y in range(ydim):
        for x in range(xdim):
            px = RGB_values[i]
            i = i+1
            im.putpixel((x,y),((px&0xF800) >> 8, (px&0x07E0) >> 3, (px&0x001F) << 3))  
    im.save('image.png')  
    im.show()    

def main():
    try:
        serialPort=serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB1', baudrate=115200,bytesize=8,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=1,timeout=0)
    except:
        print("unable to open port")
    while(1):
        if(serialPort.in_waiting>0):
            incoming=serialPort.readline().decode('ascii','ignore')
            incoming=incoming.rstrip()
            if('ET' not in incoming):
                if(not incoming):
                    incoming='0'
                print(incoming)
                RGB_list.append(incoming)
            else:
                with open('serial_python.txt','w',newline='',encoding='utf-8') as txtfile:
                    writer=csv.writer(txtfile)
                    for i in RGB_list:
                        writer.writerow([i])
                TakePicture()

I'm using PIL to take every value from the array and generate a pixel, but why is not wroking? I take this values through serial port and convert those values to integer and fill another array to later generated every pixel.
At first I though it was the encoding, but then I realize that it seems something related with the way the image is generated. I found something related to this in the forum and many used np arrays.

You are assuming the values are RGB 5:6:5.  Do you know that for certain?  Are you getting 153,600 bytes?  It LOOKS like you have a stride problem -- as if you're getting 321 pixels per line instead of 320.

Why are you reading it as ASCII?  Do you really get newlines?

Hi Tim, I'm sending the image from the other side of the port as uint16 RGB565 using sprintf with \r\n as ending. the uint16 got 5 bits R, 6 bits G and 5 bits B. Instead of 153600 uint8, Im sending 76800 values as uint16

OK, I did a hex dump of the scanlines.  You're getting 3 extra pixels per scanline.  It also looks like there may be some status bytes sent every 72 pixels or so.  See the black speckles in your image?  What's generating this data?  Are you reading directly from a CCD sensor?  It's not coming from a digital source, because the edges aren't sharp.

You shouldn't be using readline() at all for sending binary uint16 data because your image itself could contain pixels which are the same as linefeeds and carriage returns. You should use read() with exactly the number of bytes in a frame, and use write() on the other end. You can't treat an image as "lines of text".

Also, you shouldn't be doing all those putpixel() calls in a loop. It's sl-o-o-o-o-ow. Make a Numpy array of uint16 and then use Numpy to shift/AND/OR the elements into a (h x w x 3) array and call PIL.Imagefromarray() passing the Numpy array. Faster, shorter, less error-prone.

Following on from my comments - you shouldn't treat a binary image as lines of text delimited by linefeeds, because the image is binary and any pixel could appear exactly the same and indistinguishable from a linefeed. Remember readline() reads bytes till it finds linefeeds, so you need to use read() and specify the number of bytes in a frame and use write() to send the data from the other end.
Let's make an RGB565 file on disk with ImageMagick with your dimensions:
magick logo: -resize 320x240\! -flip -define bmp:subtype=RGB565 bmp2:- | tail -c $((320*240*2)) > rgb565.bin

That image looks like this - although StackOverflow cannot display RGB565 so this is actually a PNG:

Now your code would look like this:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path

# Define parameters
w, h = 320, 240

# Load image data from file - you would read this many bytes from Serial instead
buffer = Path('rgb565.bin').read_bytes()

# Make buffer into h x w Numpy array of uint16 and split out channels by shifting
rgb565 = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype=np.uint16).reshape((h,w))
R = (rgb565 >> 8) & 0xf8
G = (rgb565 >> 3) & 0xfc
B = (rgb565 << 3)

# Make 3 arrays of h x w into one RGB888 array of h x w x 3
RGB888 = np.dstack((R, G, B)).astype(np.uint8)
Image.fromarray(RGB888).show()


Hi Mark, your code works like a charm, but from serial port Im still getting the frist image I upload. In here you can look at the data incoming from port. https://pastecode.io/s/gzqr9qvu
If I copy this data from CuteCom and us it as array in python, I got the image display.
But If I got this data from serial port (coming from serial port and generate using sprintf) and converted to int in python still getting image distorted.

Ugh! Sending the image as text is horribly inefficient. When you transmit an RGB565 pixel, it should take 16 bits (5 + 6 + 5) also known as 2 bytes (i.e. 16 bits). If you transmit 65535, as text (like your pastecode file) that was 6 bytes, i.e. 6, 5, 5, 3, 5 and the comma ,. So you have generated 6 bytes instead of 2 and therefore it will take 3 times as long to transmit... over serial... which is already slow.
